# Is "apart from watch TV" a correct pattern?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I came across the sentence "Apart from watch TV, I did nothing all weekend." and I was confused with the pattern " apart from watch TV". I think it should be " apart from watching TV". Is my thought correct?

Answer (score 2):

`From` is a preposition and therefore should be followed by a noun-phrase, which in this case would be `watching TV`.

Comment: Agreed. Should be watching TV

Answer (score 0):

It should be written this way:

> "Apart from **watching** TV..."

You must use a gerund here because a gerund is a verbal that acts as a noun. In this instance, if the gerund phrase ("watching TV") were replaced with a pronoun, it would read this way:

> "Apart from **it**..."

I hope this might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck!